# How does On The Tangle voting relate to git/merckle trees?

Tags: consensus

I have heard from Moog that the branches of the Tangle are like branch's of a git repo and essentially each commit is a transaction. How does thus relate to the Tangle being able to form finality or consensus? I don't fully understand the analogy.